# Access internal variable in different functions

Tags: swift

Here is a very silly question for you Swift experts: How could I access an internal variable of a class in different functions? Here is an example:

```
class SomeClass {
  var vc: NSString?
  internal func defVC() {
    if let vc = "hi" as? NSString {
        println("Successfully defined vc as \(vc)")
    }
  }
  internal func whatsVC() {
    println(vc)
  }
}
let hmm = SomeClass()
hmm.defVC() // 'Successfully defined vc as hi'
hmm.whatsVC() // 'nil'
```

I would expect vc to have been defined as 'hi' for the class `hmm`, but that isn't the case. What are some changes I can make so that `vc` is accessible only within a class instance but to all of the internal functions inside that class instance?

Thanks!

Comment: How could the compiler let you get pass `if let vc = "hi"`?

Comment: Sorry, it was `"hi" as? NSString`. I'll fix it!

Comment: This "fix" doesn't change anything. You never assign a value to your `vc` property. You only assign a value to a local variable named `vc`.

Comment: You're not setting the `vc` instance variable; your `if let` statement assigns the value to a *new* variable named `vc` which shadows your instance variable.

Comment: Ah! I just started learning Swift yesterday and I'm a complete idiot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't assign any value to the `vc` property:

```
if let vc = "hi" as? NSString {
    // vc is a local variable of type NSString
    // you need to set the value for vc the instance property
    self.vc = vc
}
```

Also, you should use Swift's native `String`, not ObjC's `NSString` unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll check it as the correct answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: I'm actually trying to implement an SDK that was written in ObjC (which I don't know anything about either) inside a Swift project

Comment: `NSString` properties are automatically bridged into `String` in Swift. Better check what type `vc` really is by holding Option and click on the `instance` property

Comment: And use `print` instead of `println`, which went away in Swift 2.

Answer (score 0):

`var vc: NSString?` & `if let vc = "hi" as? NSString`

Both `vc` are different variables and occupy different memory locations. `if let` always create a new variable, with a scope of its own (from `if to {}`).

In your code:

`var vc: NSString?` is declared as optional string but never allocated memory/value.

 While in if statement, it creates new constant variable, which can't allocate memory/value to `var vc: NSString?`

```
if let vc = "hi" as? NSString {
        println("Successfully defined vc as \(vc)")
} // ends scope of `vc` declared with if statement
```

Try this, and see:

```
class SomeClass {
  var vc: NSString?
  internal func defVC() {
    if let vc = "hi" as? NSString {
        self.vc = vc
        println("vc = \(vc)")   // result - vc = hi
        println("self.vc = \(self.vc)") // result - vc = optional(hi)
    }
  }
  internal func whatsVC() {
    println(vc)
  }
}
let hmm = SomeClass()
hmm.defVC()   // result - vc = hi
hmm.whatsVC() // result - vc = optional(hi)
```